# css checkbox with changing label

Tags: css, checkbox, toggle

Trying to make a checkbox-based css toggle button with changing content. [Here's](http://codepen.io/0leg/pen/fLKts) current code

How to make A disappearing when the button toggles to B?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please post your code here instead

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```
p > input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label>span:before {
    content: '';  
}
```

[Here is a demo.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mlDsx)

Answer (score 0):

fixed it

http://codepen.io/dennym/pen/qkwnD

add

```
p > input[type="checkbox"] +label:after {
content: 'A';
  text-indent: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FF00FF;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 7px;


  }
```

and remove the the `content: 'A'` in the span.